# The data refresh on the page is inconsistent

Tags: nginx, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, uwsgi

My English is not very good, but I try to speak clearly

I found a problem on my website, when I added or updated the contents of the database to the website, the data on the website was always inconsistent.

For example, after I added an article, I kept refreshing the list of articles, and sometimes the new article appeared and sometimes it didn't.

This does not happen when I debug locally, but only when I deploy to a server using uwsgi+nginx. I think it's a problem with uwsgi+nginx, but I don't know how to deal with it.

Below is a screenshot of my uwsgi and nginx logs

Uwsgi screenshots:

[image]

The figure shows that the data size of GET is not consistent. The missing part is the article I added

**This is my configuration for uwsgi**

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:5000
chdir = /home/ciel/blog
plugin = python
wsgi-file = manager.py
callable = app
processes = 1
threads = 2
stats = 127.0.0.1:9191
buffer-size= 65535
pidfile=/home/ciel/blog/uwsgi.pid
```

**This is my nginx configuration**

```
server {
        listen  80;
        server_name  127.0.0.1;
        access_log  /home/ciel/blog/logs/access.log;
        error_log  /home/ciel/blog/logs/error.log;
        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:5000;
            uwsgi_buffers 16 16k;
            uwsgi_buffer_size 32k;
            uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR  /home/ciel/blog;
            uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT manager:app;
}
}
```

---

**Sqlalchemy session**

```
@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
    db.session.remove()
```

There is nothing wrong with local debugging. Are uwsgi and nginx configured incorrectly?

If the problem is not clearly described, I will continue to supplement the description

Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: Sounds like your app isn't cleaning up the sqla session properly, can you show your app/sqla configuration?

Comment: I thought so before, but the problem remained when I added code to close the session.I don't know how to write code in comments, so I put the code in the question.Please look at the Sqlalchemy session

Comment: That looks right...as long as you are calling it on the correct app instance. Have you only got one `app = Flask(__name__)` call in your code? If so, that's about all the help I can offer without a reproducible example.

Comment: Yes,I only have one app to call.Thanks for your help.